# how to make grdview column hyperlink to other pages?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

i have gridview with data source from sql. currently , one of the column , which is total guarantor, all the data is linked to same pages. but i want to make the header'Total column' hyperlink or clickable to other pages instead of the data in the Total Guarantor column .

below is the code I used:

```
           <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="Total Guarantor" DataNavigateUrlFields="Total Guarantor"  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="guarantoedetails.aspx?custno={0}" Text="Total Guarantor" HeaderText="Total Guarantor" />
```

Comment: So what you are trying is to get the related row data when you click on the Total column, then it should redirect to another page with details. Is it?

Comment: no, right now, the data in the Total column is being hyperlinked/redirect to other pages (just like the code). Instead of the data, i want the Total column(Header) to be hyperlink to other pages .

Comment: The header could be made as HyperLink. But what's the point of doing so and how would you expect to redirect to other pages?

Comment: when i try to make into hyperlink, the data from database could not be retrieved. if I did not change the code, it will confuse the user , thinking that by clicking the hyperlink data will redirect to different pages , while , it will redirect to the same pages. by clicking the hyperlink header, it will redirect to more details of the column data.

Comment: Could you share a sample how you expect it?

Comment: name |quantity (Quantity header should be hyperlink)
------ | ------
apple   | 1

Comment: i'm sorry , i don't know how to describe it :(

Comment: No problem. Just take a screen shot of your project and edit your desired output. So when I click quantity, will it redirect to apple details?

Comment: i cannot paste on the comment , as i already take the screenshot. yes,it will redirect to details of the apple :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OnRowCreated` event for this.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is the header row
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        //the header cell number where to put the link
        int cellNumber = 1;

        //cast the cell in the header
        TableCell headerCell = e.Row.Cells[cellNumber];

        //create a hyperlink
        HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
        link.Text = "myLink";
        link.NavigateUrl = "/otherPage.aspx";

        //remove existing controls from the cell
        headerCell.Controls.Clear();

        //add the hyperlink to the cell
        headerCell.Controls.Add(link);
    }
}
```

VB

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    'check if the row is the header row
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header) Then
        'the header cell number where to put the link
        Dim cellNumber As Integer = 1

        'cast the cell in the header
        Dim headerCell As TableCell = e.Row.Cells(cellNumber)

        'create a hyperlink
        Dim link As HyperLink = New HyperLink
        link.Text = "myLink"
        link.NavigateUrl = "/otherPage.aspx"

        'remove existing controls from the cell
        headerCell.Controls.Clear

        'add the hyperlink to the cell
        headerCell.Controls.Add(link)
    End If        
End Sub
```